# Could not run a batch file (.bat) in a servlet application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, batch-file, process

I try to run a batch file from the servlet application. I could not get any response.It shows no error or warning.The same code works in simple java program.I referred following link for batch file execution

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html
 http://p2p.wrox.com/servlets/71150-invoking-batch-file-servlet.html

I read both the inputstream and errorstream of the process but no response.please help to run a batch file from servlet.Here my code

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                String cmdarr[] = new String[4];
                cmdarr[0] = "cmd.exe";
                cmdarr[1] = "/c";
                cmdarr[2] = "start";
                cmdarr[3] = "C://notepad.bat";
                Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    try {
                        out.println("Start Running the batch file\n");
                        Process p = run.exec(cmdarr);
                        p.waitFor();
                        out.println("Completed:");
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        out.println("Exception"+e);
                    }

    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you including 'start' in the command array? Also I think C:// should be C:\\. However, either of these problems should result in an error printed to the errorstream - so I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @SiKelly Now I changed the code as you said, but still have same problem..Please help me to solve the prob.

Comment: It would be easier if we could get it to output some errors. Try calling out.flush() before you call out.close()

Comment: @SiKelly Here there is no error occur it shows in the browers as "Start Running the batch file Completed:"

Comment: And you are printing both errorstream and inputstream to the response?

Comment: @SiKelly No, only Input stream.But when getting into Input-stream class browser loading for long time no response.